# Create Cron job to run after x hours

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

I'm using [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for scheduling jobs and creating recurring job as:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => BackGroundJobManager.FirstJob(), Cron.Daily(4));
```

This runs the job daily at 4 AM. How can I configure a cron job to run after every 4 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cron expression to schedule something every four hours is e.g.:

```
0 */4 * * *
```

You could build that expression with `Cron.HourInterval(4)`, but it seems to be [deprecated](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/5c08eb4afd31d5244c13fc0a2f2ab142b63a6122/src/Hangfire.Core/Cron.cs#L240). Since those methods just return the `cron` expression as a string, you could just build your own and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the HourInterval function is being deprecated, you could just create your own as all it does is return the cron schedule.

```
public static string HourInterval(int interval)
{
    return string.Format("0 */{0} * * *", (object) interval);
}
```